# How do I confer CSS properties upon elements retrieved from $.ajax()?

Tags: css, ajax, jquery-mobile

I loaded some HTML from another page via `$.ajax`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/getInfo',
            context: $('#contentBox'),
            success: function(data) {
                $(this).html(data);
            }
        });
    });

 </script>

 <style type="text/css">
     #makeMeRed {color: red !important;}
 </style>

 <div id="contentBox"></div>
```

The code loads this HTML into the div with ID `contentBox`:

```
<p id="makeMeRed">I'm supposed to be red.</p>
```

However, the paragraph is not red. How can I give elements loaded via Ajax CSS properties?

---

To be specific, jQuery Mobile CSS is not rendering in the HTML I pulled from Ajax:
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your markup <strike>is</strike> was invalid

```
<style="text/css">
```

should be

```
<style type="text/css">
```

Otherwise CSS rules should be applied fine to HTML loaded via AJAX.

---

**Update** - Tips for debugging unmatched CSS:

- Use the element inspector to find which rules are beign matched.
- Check the markup is what you expected after you pulled it by AJAX.
- Ensure there are no inline styling or other `<style>` tags in the new markup that could conflict.

Comment: Oh sorry. Thanks, that is true. Nonetheless, the code is still not working.

Comment: @DavidFaux hmm.. try looking at matched CSS rules on the element inspector

Comment: Thanks, apparently the CSS works if one is not using jQuery Mobile.